# division above the data type limits

Tags: c++, python, assembly

I am looking to write an algorithm that is required to do division of two unreasonably large numbers (Both thousands of digits long).

Is there a library that already exists in python or c++ (or assembly) that does this? Is it even possible?

There arn't any time constraints or anything

Comment: first thing that comes to mind is numpy. Since it's used for scientific tasks my guess is that it has the means to handle huge numbers.

Comment: Please clarify your needs. I n the question you ask for a way to handle numbers "thousands of digits long", but in the comments you say you actually want to handle multi-gigabyte numbers. Those are two quite different needs. A number "thousands of digits long" is a few kilobytes long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python already supports big integers, so the only missing functionality is rational numbers. This is provided by the *fractions* module:

```
from fractions import Fraction
>>> print float( Fraction(2**54343) / Fraction( 2**54347 + 1 ) )
0.0625
>>> print Fraction(2**54343) / Fraction( 2**54347 + 1 )
# ... very long exact answer expressed as a fraction ...
```

Comment: is there stuff above bigint?

Comment: @Darcys22 Python uses big integers by default (but not rationals). 2**54343 is an exponentiation which results in a 16359-digit number. The other number is of a similar size. You can simply type "2**54343" at a Python prompt and it will show the number.

Comment: I'm thinking bigger than that. With 2**23432532652 I'm getting a memory error which is why I'm thinking its not a language problem but a limit enforced by page sizes or something

Comment: I was being conservative when I said thousands of digits

Comment: I'm not sure you realize how big a number 2**23432532652 is. That is a 23432532652-bit number which would require more than 2.5 gigabytes merely to store. Are you sure your requirements include that? Can you give an idea of what you're trying to do? Whatever software you use you will always be limited by available storage and memory.

Comment: yeah I know, its huge. What I'm wanting to do is exactly that, taking a file that is several GB and working on it. As I said before Im not even sure its possible

Comment: And the multi-gigabyte file file contains a single number? Stored in binary or decimal? The proper way to work on such a file would be to load it gradually from the disk and work on it a little bit at the time. That's not what conventional bignum libraries do. However, this sounds like an instance of the XY problem. If you think that e.g. any sort of sensible cryptographic scheme requires this, you are almost certainly doing something wrong. What is the high-level task that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It doesn't matter how its stored. I don't think that it has ever been done this way, I get that breaking it down is the conventional way and way easier but is working on the huge file possible. Say the file is just a multi-gig binary of the number I want to use, then divide it by another multi-gig binary?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you could use [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html) library:

> The Multiprecision Library provides integer, rational and
>   floating-point types in C++ that have more range and precision than
>   C++'s ordinary built-in types

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s(100, '0');
    s.at(0) = '1';
    boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float_1000 f1(std::move(s));
    boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float_1000 f2 = f1 / 42;
    std::cout << f2.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is that code working? Is it working its way through a string rather than storing it as a datatype?

Comment: @Darcys22, `Boost.Multiprecision` is just a wrapper for some popular multiprecision libraries. In the example below `mpfr` library is used. I don't know how numbers stored in that library, sorry.

Comment: @Darcys22: If by "string" you mean a printable string of decimal digits, then no. It represents large numbers as an array (or string, if you like) of smaller lumps (probably 32 or 64 bits, to match the datatypes the processor can work with directly), and performs arithmetic on that using algorithms like "long division".

Comment: Note that mpfr_float_1000 is a floating-point type which guarantees at least 1000 decimal digits precision. If you need completely exact results you should use the rational types which also exist in Boost.Multiprecision.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I mean that a string doesn't have a constrant to its size, the characters are just stored in sequential memory blocks. Do the array elements have a limit?

Comment: @Darcys22: You'd need to consult the Boost or MPFR documentation for details; but I'm fairly sure that there are dynamically allocated types which don't have any particular limit.

Comment: Might be a segmentation issue? Not something you run into very often in our post DOS nirvana